# How to use the JDialog without using JDialog 

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

sorry for the strange title, but here's the explanation.
So I have a class StudentRepository with a List of students, which were selected on a GUI (via a TableModel).
Attributes of a Student-object are:

```
int studentid

string name,surname

List<Absent> absents

List<ClassRoom> classes (as in classroom)
```

So I want to call a method that runs in the StudentRepository, that checks if if the student has absents then there should be a prompt if it is ok to be deleted and the absents should be shown while promped. Like a jDialog.

Hope I made myself understandable,
Haroun Minhas

Comment: What about [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)?

Answer (score 5):

I can't understand why you don't want to use JDialog for doing this. Here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). 
You can put whatever you want inside a JDialog even your absent list.

Comment: is this valid by the rules of OO-programming? Because I tought that GUI-parts only can be called from the GUI-package

Comment: @Haroun Minhas: I don't understand your objection. Separate model from the view is right. But how could gui components be called only inside gui package?how to fill them with your model data?

Comment: Your model sends them back to the calling object in the view. The view then presents the data it retrieved in a JDialog.